# The multi-part identifier "p.ProductID" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, apache-camel, inner-join, switchyard

I have some SQL which executes fine on mssql platform, but we I executes it from a switch yard camel flow (SQL-binding) it do not work.

The sql is

```
SELECT
p.ProductID,p.dtGTIN,p.ProductWeight      
,p.dtPurchasePriceUnit,p.dtItemGroupID,
p.dtPromotionID,p.IntroductionDate,p.dtOnOrder,
p.dtExposureGroup,p.dtPlanogram,p.ProductHeight,
p.ProductWidth,p.ProductLength,p.dtPackageSize1,
p.productHeightUOMID,p.productWidthUOMID,p.productLengthUOMID,
pn.dtProductNameDescription1,pn.dtProductNameDescription2,
pv.VendorID,pr.ReferenceNumber
FROM ODS_Product p
    JOIN ODS_ProductName pn 
ON pn.ProductID=p.ProductID and pn.BusinessUnitId=p.BusinessUnitId
    JOIN ODS_ProductVendor pv 
ON pv.ProductID=p.ProductID and pv.BusinessUnitId=p.BusinessUnitId
    LEFT JOIN ODS_dtProductReference pr 
ON (pr.ProductID=p.ProductID and pr.BusinessUnitId=p.BusinessUnitId and      
    pr.ReferenceID='SRII')
where p.ProductID=# and p.BusinessUnitId=#
```

The message is

```
Caused by exception of type com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException, 
message: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The multi-part     
identifier "p.ProductID" could not be bound.: 
org.switchyard.HandlerException: org.switchyard.HandlerException: 
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: 

PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL. SQL state  
[null]; error code [0]; com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The 
multi-part identifier "p.ProductID" could not be bound.; nested exception is 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The multi-part identifier 
"p.ProductID" could not be bound.
```

Any idea why?

Comment: The two # is parameters, which could fx be

    p.ProductID='2602_1487130'  and p.BusinessUnitId=6

Comment: Can you try isolating the problem by only querying ODS_Product to see if the parameters are being bound properly? Something like Select p.ProductID,p.dtGTIN,p.ProductWeight FROM ODS_Product p WHERE p.ProductId=#

Answer (score 0):

as per my knowledge, you cannot use **and** in Join clause. please try by removing the and part from join statements.

```
SELECT
p.ProductID,p.dtGTIN,p.ProductWeight      
,p.dtPurchasePriceUnit,p.dtItemGroupID,
p.dtPromotionID,p.IntroductionDate,p.dtOnOrder,
p.dtExposureGroup,p.dtPlanogram,p.ProductHeight,
p.ProductWidth,p.ProductLength,p.dtPackageSize1,
p.productHeightUOMID,p.productWidthUOMID,p.productLengthUOMID,
pn.dtProductNameDescription1,pn.dtProductNameDescription2,
pv.VendorID,pr.ReferenceNumber
FROM ODS_Product p
   JOIN ODS_ProductName pn 
   ON pn.ProductID=p.ProductID 
join ODS_ProductName pn1 pn1.BusinessUnitId=p.BusinessUnitId
 JOIN ODS_ProductVendor pv 
ON pv.ProductID=p.ProductID 
JOIN ODS_ProductVendor  Pv1 pv1.BusinessUnitId=p.BusinessUnitId
LEFT JOIN ODS_dtProductReference pr 
where p.ProductID=# and p.BusinessUnitId=#
```

I am not sure, but it might help you.

Comment: Thx Ram Singh, but it didnt work, gives a many,many, many  rows.

Comment: @user1073857 sorry i missed the last join to add, please add the last join and let me know if it works for you with ODS_dtProductReference table

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to it. The problem was the sql drivers prepared statement thingy. It could not interprete the "p.productId" for some reason, so when i removed all Aliases from the SQL it worked (But I dont know why):

```
 SELECT ODS_Product.ProductID,ODS_Product.dtGTIN,ODS_Product.ProductWeight
 ,ODS_Product.dtPurchasePriceUnit,ODS_Product.dtItemGroupID,
ODS_Product.dtPromotionID,ODS_Product.IntroductionDate,
ODS_Product.dtOnOrder,ODS_Product.dtExposureGroup,ODS_Product.dtPlanogram,
ODS_Product.ProductHeight,ODS_Product.ProductWidth,
ODS_Product.ProductLength,ODS_Product.dtPackageSize1,
ODS_Product.productHeightUOMID,ODS_Product.productWidthUOMID,
ODS_Product.productLengthUOMID,ODS_ProductName.dtProductNameDescription1,
ODS_ProductName.dtProductNameDescription2,ODS_ProductVendor.VendorID,
ODS_dtProductReference.ReferenceNumber
FROM ODS_Product
JOIN ODS_ProductName ON ODS_ProductName.ProductID=ODS_Product.ProductID
 and ODS_ProductName.BusinessUnitId=ODS_Product.BusinessUnitId
JOIN ODS_ProductVendor ON ODS_ProductVendor.ProductID=ODS_Product.ProductID
 and ODS_ProductVendor.BusinessUnitId=ODS_Product.BusinessUnitId
LEFT JOIN ODS_dtProductReference ON         
ODS_dtProductReference.ProductID=ODS_Product.ProductID 
 and ODS_dtProductReference.BusinessUnitId=ODS_Product.BusinessUnitId 
 and ODS_dtProductReference.ReferenceID='SRII')
where ODS_Product.ProductID='2602_1487130'
    and ODS_Product.BusinessUnitId=6
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing implicit joins with explicit joins. That is allowed, but you need to be aware of how to do that properly.

The thing is, explicit joins (the ones that are implemented using the JOIN keyword) take precedence over implicit ones (the 'comma' joins, where the join condition is specified in the WHERE clause).